# What is the meaning of "exports" in the index.js file from a ReactJS project?

Tags: reactjs, browserify, commonjs, react-router

I'm already familiar with ReactJS and CommonJS. I know what the `exports` mean, but looking at [this index.js](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/index.js) file from [ReactRouter](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) library, I don't quite understand the meaning of `exports` in this context.

When I `browserify` this project starting from the `index.js` file, will the results of `exports` be defined in the global scope?

I was expecting something like this:

```
ReactRouter.DefaultRoute = require('./components/DefaultRoute');
```

But instead, in the `index.js`, there's this:

```
exports.DefaultRoute = require('./components/DefaultRoute');
```

If I found the `exports.DefaultRoute` anywhere else, but in the `index.js` file, I would understand it. But as **I'm not requiring index.js anywhere**, how would I be able to reference `DefaultRoute`?

Will this be in the global scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package.json` appears to be using `index.js` on line 13.  I believe that index.js is the main module file exported by webpack. So `require('ReactRouter')` would include all the exports from said index.js.

Comment: Yeah. Just a way to batch up all the requires to make the files with the actual code a little easier to read.